# assign large value to int data type

Tags: java, int

when i try to compile this program, it gave an error  `integer number too large: 11111111111`. how to correct this ?

```
class PrimeFactor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int primeLimit = 11111111111;
        int sum = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < primeLimit + 1; i++) {
            if((primeLimit%i) == 0) {
                sum *= i;
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            if(sum == primeLimit) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `long` primitive type, if your number is not too large. Long uses twice the number of bits `int` uses and can represent integral numbers up to [`Long.MAX_VALUE = 2^63-1`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE):

```
long primeLimit = 11111111111L;
```

Of course you have to change the types of other variables, e.g. `i` and `sum`, too.

If you want to use larger numbers, use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

```
BigInteger primeLimit = new BigInteger("11111111111111111111111");
```

If you want to use `BigInteger`, the normal arithmetic operators won't work anymore. You have to use the methods of `BigInteger` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A signed integer can hold values as large as 2^31 - 1, which is 2147483647. Using a `long` or some other alternative will work.